# Non linearly separable data to linearly separable data in the same dimension or lower dimension

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, svm, kernel-trick

In continuation to this question, [Non linear to linearly seperable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449791/can-non-linearly-separable-data-always-be-made-linearly-separable)
I am trying to understand if we do not want to transform to a higher dimension is it possible to still find a feature map that maps non linearly separable data into linearly separable data. If yes whats the intuition. For example in the image below I am trying to check if there is any 1D transformation I can use to find linearly separable data.
Also can we find transformation in lower dimension. Any reference material to read would be helpful as well.

[image: Example if it can be transformed to linearly separable data]

Comment: Good question; note that it's not enough just to have *some* map, we need one that's continuous(ly differentiable).

Comment: by *assumption* there is a mapping from a given data point to its class, and using the mapping, the problem is linearly separable. ie if my feature already solves the class mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Every case is different, and it's not generally possible for every data set, but there's a very simple transformation that makes your data linearly separable:

```r
x = 1:20
y = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
f = function(x) (x - 1) %% 4

plot(x, y, main = 'Not linearly separable')
```

[image]

```r
plot(f(x), y, main = 'Linearly seperable')
```

[image]

`x %% 4` here is the modulo or remainder operator: the remainder when `x` is divided by 4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is sometimes possible. In the example you give, a point $t$ is class X precisely when $\sin(\pi t)>0$.